# How to Make horizontal graph of Truth Values in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to make a comparison of three lists of Truth values by making a graph.

I have three very long lists of boolean values (True and False) for example

```
list1 = [True,False,True,True,True,False...]
```

[image: Plot example]

Can someone please tell me the easiest way to make a graph that marks red if it is True and white or black if it is False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def morse(lists):
    for i,list_ in enumerate(lists):
        for j,value in enumerate(list_):
            if value:
                plt.plot([j,j+1],[i,i],'r',linewidth=5.0)
    plt.axis([0,j+1,-1,i+1])
    labels=['List'+str(i) for i in range(1,len(lists)+1)]
    plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off'
    ) 
    plt.tick_params(
    axis='y',          # changes apply to the y-axis
    which='minor',     # minor ticks are affected
    left='off',        # ticks along the left edge are off
    right='off'        # ticks along the right edge are off
    ) 
    plt.xlabel('index')
    plt.yticks(range(len(lists)),labels)
    plt.show()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
morse([[True,False,True],[False,False,True]])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please update the code to add the index of the list on the horizontal axis.
eg 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Just add `plt.xticks(range(len(lists[0])))` and change `which='both'`with `which='minor'` on the x-axis

Comment: the list is too large (1000 indexes). How can i display intervals in these ticks? (on every hundredth index)?

Comment: sorry for bothering you for such an easy task.
I realized that it can be done by using 
    plt.xticks(range(0,len(lists[0]),100))